# httpModule in App_code will not load when debugging locally

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple .net web application and implemented a class based off of IHttp.  I copied the example directly from Microsoft documentation.  The class is located in the app_code directory.

The problem is that whenever I run the application I get the following error:

HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'httpModuleEx.App_Code.HelloWorldClass'

Here is my web.config entry to register the new class:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <remove name="HelloWorldClass"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="HelloWorldClass" type="httpModuleEx.App_Code.HelloWorldClass"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

I have tried many variations on referencing the HelloWorldClass here but none worked for me.

I also tried making the build action of the HelloWorldClass.cs file (located under the app_code directory) "compile".

Below is the code from the HelloWorldClass.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace httpModuleEx.App_Code
{
    public class HelloWordClass : IHttpModule
    {

        // In the Init function, register for HttpApplication
        // events by adding your handlers.
        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            application.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
            application.EndRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest));
        }

        private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs args)
        {
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
            HttpContext context = application.Context;
            string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
            string fileExtension =
                VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
            if (fileExtension.Equals(".aspx"))
            {
                context.Response.Write("<h1><font color=red>" +
                    "HelloWorldModule: Beginning of Request" +
                    "</font></h1><hr>");
            }
        }

        private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs args)
        {
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
            HttpContext context = application.Context;
            string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
            string fileExtension =
                VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
            if (fileExtension.Equals(".aspx"))
            {
                context.Response.Write("<hr><h1><font color=red>" +
                    "HelloWorldModule: End of Request</font></h1>");
            }

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because you've spelled World as Word in your code :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Thank you!  Also I changed the web.config to:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <remove name="HelloWorldClass"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="HelloWorldClass" type="httpModuleEx.App_Code.HelloWorldClass, httpModuleEx"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```